# 2D density plot using pandas and seaborn

Tags: pandas, seaborn, visualization, heatmap, density-plot

I'm trying to plot a heatmap like:

[image: Text]

(https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.kdeplot.html - last plot on the page)

But when I try this with my code I get:

[image]

My Pandas dataframe exists of two cols (x and y - both int64) and a number of rows. :

[image]

My code:

```
sns.kdeplot(data=dataFrame, fill=True, thresh=0, levels=100, cmap="mako", cbar=True)
```

My question is now how do I get rid of the contours, fill the background an make a smooth colorbar on the side?

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem. What version of seaborn are you using? The link you provided is for seaborn v.0.11

Comment: 0.10 apparently, I thought anaconda always used the latest packages. Guess not. I'll try older docs/ upgrading seaborn. Thanks for your comment!

Comment: After updating seaborn I still get the same plot, but now with a warning: "UserWarning: Passing a 2D dataset for a bivariate plot is deprecated in favor of kdeplot(x, y), and it will cause an error in future versions. Please update your code.
  warnings.warn(warn_msg, UserWarning)"

Comment: Did you try `sns.kdeplot(data=..., x='x', y='y', ...)`? Maybe also try to upgrade to the latest matplotlib version.

Comment: Updating all packages and using x and y indeed did help, thanks guys!